# Couchbase - smart cross data center replication (XCDR)

Tags: couchbase

I have 2 Couchbase clusters. 1 for real time work and 1 for back-end data query.
I wish to replicate only 10% of the data from the real time bucket to the back-end because it's used for statistically annalists.

Note one: I know it's not possible by the UI, I'm looking for a way to write some-kind of extension for it that could "sit" in the middle of the XCDR and filter it.

Note two: As I understand Elastic-Search are using the replication feature to get noticed for changes on the cluster and build there own indexes. If I could "listen" for those notification myself I could take it from there, reading and sending the relevant data myself.

Any ideas on how I can make it work?

**==NOTES==**

1. I found the following link: http://blog.couchbase.com/xdcr-aspnet-and-nancy, this give a basic example of `Sinatra` project which XDCR can connect to. But there is no link to a documentation on the Rest API for one which doesn't want to work with `Sinatra`.
2. As for @Cihan question, replication 10% of the data is the basic use I wish for and for that I can use only the key. But in general I probably like to munipulate the data and also be able to merge it to an existing data - that would be a case if I have 2 real time clusters replicating to 1 back-end cluster.

Answer (score 2):

Don't have anything built in today to do this. You could set up XDCR and delete the data that you don't need on the destination cluster but it may reappear as updates happen so your cleanup will have to continuously run. would a method like that work? 
By the way we do plan to have the facility in future. one comment that would be helpful for me is what type of a filtering would suffice in your case? can we filter with a prefix only to achieve your case or would you need a more sophisticated filtering expression?
thanks
Cihan Biyikoglu

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. when you say "we do plan to have the facility.." can I guess that you work for Couchbase?
I will answer your questions as a note to my question.

Comment: I'm very interested in this filtering capability as well. As I understand it, it is not recommended to have too many buckets in couchbase. However, the XDCR replication to elasticsearch is at the bucket level. We would like send different types of objects to different schemas in ES. That doesn't seem possible with the current XDCR replication.